# What would cause Microsoft Jet OLEDB SELECT to miss a whole column?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oledb

I'm importing an `.xls` file using the following connection string:

```
If _
    SetDBConnect( _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & filepath & _
        ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1""", True) Then
```

This has been working well for parsing through several Excel files that I've come across.  However, with this particular file, when I `SELECT *` into a `DataTable`, there is a whole column of data, `Item Description`, missing from the `DataTable`.  Why?

Here are some things that may set this particular workbook apart from the others that I've been working with:

- The workbook has a freeze pane consisting of the first 24 rows (however, all of these rows appear in the `DataTable`)
- There is some weird cell highlighting going on throughout the workbook

That's pretty much it.  I can't see anything that would make the `Item Description` column not import correctly.  Its data is comprised of all `Strings` that really have no special characters apart from `&`. Additionally, each data entry in this column is a maximum of 20 characters.  What is happening?  Is there any other way I can get all of the data?  Keep in mind I have to use the original file and I cannot alter it, as I want this to ultimately be an automated process.

Thanks!

Comment: The missing column is at index 4. Removing the space from "Item Description" has no effect.  Interestingly enough, all columns have two column headers (both the exact same).  One is in a hidden row, index 18, inside the freeze pane, the other is at row index 24, just after all of the garbage data that is hidden.  Good thoughts, though.

Comment: Another good idea.  Deleting that column has no effect on the resulting DataTable.  That is, the problem must be specific to that column.  Thank you for helping me diagnose this strange issue.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling You were absolutely correct in your assumption.  There was a formula in that column near the top, so no data would load past that point.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Neat! I'll move all of these comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some initial thoughts/questions: Is the missing column the very first column? What happens if you remove the space within "Item Description"? Stupid question, but does that column have a column header?

-- **EDIT 1** --

If you delete that column, does the problem move to another column (the new index 4), or is the file complete. My reason for asking this -- is the problem specific to data in that column/header, or is the problem more general, on index 4.

-- **EDIT 2** --

Ok, so since we know it's that column, we know it's either the header, or the rows. Let's concentrate on rows for now. Start with that ampersand; dump it, and see what happens. Next, work with the first 50% of rows. Does deleting that subset affect anything? What about the latter 50% of rows? If one of those subsets changes the result, you ought to be able to narrow it down to an individual row (hopefully not plural) by halfing your selection each time.

My guess is that you're going to find a unicode character or something else funky is one of the cells. Maybe there's a formula or, as you mentioned, some of that "weird cell highlighting."

Answer (score 0):

It's been years since I worked with excel access, but I recall some problems with excel grouping content into some areas that would act as table inside each sheet. Try copy/paste the content from the problematic sheet to a new workbook and connect to that workbook. If this works you may be able to investigate a bit further about areas.